# Open file dialog showing white squares instead of text after upgrading LTS from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dialog, atom

**Problem**: when opening Atom IDE "Open File" or "Open Folder" dialog the names of files and folders is not encoded properly and only white squares are shown.

**Description**: This has happened right after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. The same issue does not happen when opening folders from applications such as Gedit or VLC.

The dialog, as shown by Atom, has the following aspect:

[Bad encoding on Open File dialog ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9yQJ.png)

Comment: Does this happen when you launch Atom using `atom --safe`?

Comment: Yes @idleberg. There is no difference and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's some other way to fix this, but I uninstalled Atom and reinstalled it on my Ubuntu 18.04 to "fix" the problem.